# .Net YouTube API Invalid Credentials

Tags: .net, youtube-api

We're in the process of test launching a website that makes use of the .Net YouTube API (v 2.2). It of course works fine in development and staging, but in production we're getting an Google.GData.Client.InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials exception. The credentials used are exactly the same as tested in staging. We are using the

`new YouTubeRequestSettings(applicationName, devkey, username, password)`

overload.

I have tripled checked the credentials, and have logged them in production to verify that they match.

Wondering if anyone is aware of any other potential causes of this issue? Firewall perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the Google is preventing the login attempt because it came from an unknown location. I noticed this in the Account > Security > Recent Activity section (https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?service=youtube&hl=en_US).

Once you have verified the login attempt, you must change the account password for subsequent login attempts to work.